# What happens to flagged users?

Tags: discussion, flags

I am not sure what would happen to users whose posts have been flagged.  Recently, I had 2 successful flags (on 2 comments) from the same user, but I don't see anything happening (like a reputation decrease or a ban).  Perhaps I didn't look closely enough.  Could someone tell me what happens to flagged users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every infraction results in a suspension. Sometimes they result in warnings without suspensions. Other times, if the infraction is *very* minor, we just shrug it off and don't even warn the user.

Your job is to remain vigilant and let us know if the user continues to engage in bad behavior. But once you flag a user for bad behavior the idea is to let us handle it and not worry about it.

Comment: Could I get examples of minor infractions, or like how they are different to major ones? Thanks

Comment: @XcoderX: A comment that sounds only slightly peeved from an otherwise usually kind and polite user (maybe they're just having a bad day). If it becomes a pattern then we step in and say, "hey, you need to tone it down, or take a break if you need one."